# JSX in fuction donot update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Can anyone give an answer?**

Unable to update the state when I click getbtn -> placeRange pass jsx to setbtn ->then unable to update the State when Silde the Range.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Stack() {
  const [value, setvalue] = useState(0);
  const [btn, setbtn] = useState(<></>);

  function placeRange() {
    const jsx = (
      <>
        <input
          type="range"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setvalue(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <h1>{value}</h1>
      </>
    );
    setbtn(jsx);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={placeRange}>getrange</button>
      {btn}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me.

Here's a working example at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-napier-nguny?file=/src/App.js:0-512)

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setvalue] = useState(0);
  const [btn, setbtn] = useState(<></>);

  function placeBtn() {
    const jsx = (
      <>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setvalue(1);
          }}
        >
          Convert to 1
        </button>
      </>
    );
    setbtn(jsx);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
      <button onClick={placeBtn}>getbtn</button>
      {btn}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I update the code https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sun-4h7sd?file=/src/App.js:0-503

Comment: How to Solve this???

Comment: You are setting the JSX in the state. onChange on your value attribute, you're not changing that state to re-render this. This should be rendered conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve, this is not clear enough for me.
From your code it seems you are trying to set an input range in place when clicking the button, then, you want this range to update the number below it.

If this is the case I suggest the following solution:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Stack() {
  const [value, setvalue] = useState(0);
  const [showRange, setShowRange] = useState(false);

  function placeRange() {
    setShowRange(!showRange);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={placeRange}>getrange</button>
      {showRange && (
        <>
          <input
            type="range"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setvalue(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <h1>{value}</h1>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: i just want to know why the value <h1>{value} </h1> is not updated in my code. i cannot change the pattern  in my main project.